# Zooming to selected feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, select, zoom

I want to create a function that selects a feature and zooms to it (similar in QGIS). Therefore there is following function:

```py
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)

def zoomTo(self):
    layer = self.vlayer
    atable = self.ui.table
        
    selectList=[]
    for i in atable.selectionModel().selectedRows():
        ID = atable.item(i.row(),0).text()
        selectList.append(int(ID))
  
    layer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
```

The selected features are highlighted on the map. But I have no idea how to make a "zoom" to the selected features or some kind of focus them in the middle of the map.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set the extents of the map canvas to the extents of the selections:

```py
box = layer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Answer (score 10):

Zoom to selected features can also be performed by triggering the "Zoom to Selection" option of View menu.

```py
eMenu = self.iface.viewMenu()
eMenu.actions() [12].trigger()
```

*Note:* The index number may vary with different QGIS versions.

---

Or more directly:

```py
iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
```

Answer (score 0):

**# The first a QMessageBox display all selected features:**

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer();
fts = lyr.selectedFeatures();
ftsCount = lyr.selectedFeatureCount();
sFts = str(ftsCount);
msgBox = QMessageBox();
msgBox.setText(sFts +' selected features');
msgBox.exec_();
```

**# Second zoom to selected features:**

```
iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger();
```

Comment: Python does not require `;`